# time data does not match format. What am i missing?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

2018-11-07 01:11:51

I have the above date as a value the of:

```
minpull= df.timestamp[0]
```

then, when I run it through the code below,

```
minpull1 = dt.strptime('minpull','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I get the following error,

```
 ValueError: time data 'minpull' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I dont understand what i'm missing.
Thanks

Comment: What language is this? Please add the appropriate tag(s). And just a guess, but maybe you meant to pass the variable `minpull` to `strptime()` instead of the literal string `'minpull'`? If so you need to remove the quotes.

Comment: python. That looks like it did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: check the type of minpull, it must be str. you should change it to datetime using pd.to_datetime.